# Checking whether the current WPF app is running or not?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml, process

How to check programmatically whether my WPF app is working or not right now?, Like App.PrevInstance in VB. 
Please suggest me a simple method, i am beginner.

Here my code,

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);
    var runningProcessByName = Process.GetProcessesByName("TCLCGFP");
    if (runningProcessByName.Length == 0)
    {
        //Process.Start("TCLCGFP.exe");
        new TraacsClcProcess();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Application is already Running.","TCLCGFP",MessageBoxButton.OK,MessageBoxImage.Information);
    }
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

It is always showing Application is already Running :P

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking if Windows Application is running](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722198/checking-if-windows-application-is-running)

Comment: I am looking for simple code like App.PrevInstance which is using in VB.

Comment: Then update your question with exact details with what you need and what you tried already

Answer (score 3):

What most people do is use a **named Mutex object**.  Use the constructor overload that tells you if it was successfully created to find out if another process has already created one with the same name. Example for using the mutex:

```
Mutex mutex;

try
{
   mutex = Mutex.OpenExisting("SINGLEINSTANCE");

   if (mutex!= null)
   {
         Console.WriteLine("Error, 1 instance Only");
         Application.Exit();
    }
 }
 catch (WaitHandleCannotBeOpenedException ex)
 {
        mutex  = new Mutex(true, "SINGLEINSTANCE");
 }
```

You can also read this [How to determine if a previous instance of my application is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778817/how-to-determine-if-a-previous-instance-of-my-application-is-running)

Comment: I didn't get your code man..
How can i implement your code into my App.?

Answer (score 0):

You can check process name as specified in the link I gave in the comment:

```
public partial class App : System.Windows.Application
{
    public bool IsProcessOpen(string name)
    {
        foreach (Process clsProcess in Process.GetProcesses()) {
            if (clsProcess.ProcessName.Contains(name))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    // Get Reference to the current Process
    Process thisProc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
    if (IsProcessOpen("TCLCGFP.exe") == false)
    {
        //System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Application not open!");
        //System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }
    else
    {
        // Check how many total processes have the same name as the current one
        if (Process.GetProcessesByName(thisProc.ProcessName).Length > 1)
        {
            // If ther is more than one, than it is already running.
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Application is already running.");
            System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();
            return;
        }
        base.OnStartup(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: ....It is always showing that the "Application is not open".when the code -> IsProcessOpen("TraacsCLCGalileoFocalPoint.exe").


And "Application is already running" when i remove ".exe"
 like -> IsProcessOpen("TraacsCLCGalileoFocalPoint").

Comment: could you please double check name of process using Process Manager?

Comment: Double check mean , double processes with same name?

Comment: No, double check - this means - look what is the process name of your exe, is it really "TraacsCLCGalileoFocalPoint.exe"

Comment: Ya man. It is the Same which i have mentioned here,
Should i give ".exe" here?

Comment: Can you debug the code? Put the breakpoint into IsProcessOpen function and check what is wrong there

Comment: Uff.. I am not able to Rebuild now. it is showing that being used by another process... :(

Comment: No,,, There is no way to work this code in my app :(